# required java.util.ArrayList<String>,found java.lang.Object : I do not understand the reason for this error

Tags: java, foreach, arraylist

Following are some snippets from a jsp page:

```
<%! ArrayList songList = new ArrayList<String>(); %>

    <%
        songList = StoreSongLink.linkList;
        // linkList is a static variable in the class StoreSongLink
        // There the linkList is defined as public static ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
    %>

<%}  else {
       for (ArrayList<String> list : songList){}

%>
```

The code inside the else srciplet produces an error `required java.util.ArrayList<String> found java.lang.Object`. Why is this ? I do not understand  the reason for this.

***Why does the compiler say songList to be of type Object ?***

Comment: Should it not be `for (String l: songList)` and `ArrayList<String> songList = ...` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare it explicitly at the start:

```
ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you declare it like this:

```
ArrayList songList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you are saying `songList` is an `ArrayList` of `Object`s, regardless of what is to the right of the `=`.  Assignment doesn't change this, so this:

```
ArrayList songList = new ArrayList<String>();
songList = StoreSongLink.linkList;
```

does not change the type of `songList`, it's still effectively `ArrayList<Object>`.

If you fix the declaration, then your `for` loop should look like:

```
for (String list : songList){}
```

Because `songList` is array list of `String`s.  As you have it, Java extracts each `Object` from `songList` and tries to assign it to what you have declared to the left of `:`, which you have told it is an `ArrayList<String>`.  It cannot convert the `Object` to `ArrayList<String>` (especially since the `Object` is really just a `String` underneath), so it throws an error.

Comment: why shall i declare it above ? This call `songList = storeSongLink.linkList;` fetches the same

Comment: Why does the compiler say `songList` to be of type Object ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Edited answer for clarity.  Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (ArrayList<String> list : songList){} // Error is here
```

And you have define a reference of ArrayList of Object type and declared a String type  ArrayList instance which should be `ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>();` 
or `ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList();` (supports only java 7)

So the Corrected code could be like -

```
<%! List<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>(); %>
...
for (String list : songList){
}
```

Comment: but this call `songList = StoreSongLink.linkList;` does the same

Comment: why does it say `songList` to be of type object ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta - while creating ArrayList<E> if do not defined type(E) it has been granted as a Object(SuperType). And your defined reference ArrayList<E> can hold that type of or sub type of that type of objects. And it is always good approach to define type of list.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for (String s: songList) {
  // etc.
}
```

Also ensure that `StoreSongLink.linkList` is of type `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (ArrayList<String> list : songList){}
```

must be

```
for (Object list : songList){}
```

Because songList declared type is ArrayList(equal ArrayList)

Answer (score 0):

While you assign songList a new ArrayList, you're defining the songList as an arrayList (which is arrayList). That would make it okay to iterate over songList as Objects. But you're actually iterating over songList as ArrayList.

So in short, you need to switch songList to be decared to ArrayList and you need to iterate over songList with Strings, not ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is, as you probably know, a raw type, when not using parametrized `ArrayList<E>` declaration. So you effectively turned it to array list of `Object` instead of `String`, with your initialization:
 `ArrayList songList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 0):

**Your iteration is wrong in**

```
for (ArrayList<String> list : songList){}
```

`songList` contains the list of `String` elements not the list of `ArrayList<String>`

so you need to iterate this way `for (Object song: songList){}`

or

```
ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String song: songList){}
```